# Java REST - 404 resource can not be found

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, glassfish

I am trying to access a resource on my Hello world (for now) application.
However, I get this HTTP status 404 - not found when I deploy it ot Tomcat and hit the URL: localhost:8080/test/rest.
Here are my pom.xml depdendencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.26-b03</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
       <version>2.26-b03</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.26-b03</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
       <groupId>junit</groupId>
       <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
       <version>4.11</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

And here are my web.xml configurations:

```
<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld Jersey Service </servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name >jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value >com.latin.translator.app</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name >HelloWorld Jersey Service </servlet-name >
    <url-pattern >/test/*</url-pattern >
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The java code is:

```
@Path("/test")
public class Test {

    @GET
    @Produces(TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Path("/rest")
    public String test() {
        return "Great success";
    }
}
```

Do you have any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Whats the context name of the web app deployed?

Answer (score 2):

TRy localhost:8080/test/test/rest

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name >HelloWorld Jersey Service </servlet-name >
    <url-pattern >/test/*</url-pattern >
</servlet-mapping>
```

This says root is test so url is localhost:8080/test/ for jesrsey

Now

```
@Path("/test")
public class Test {
```

says now next url path is test so url is localhost:8080/test/test

```
@Path("/rest")
    public String test() {
        return "Great success";
    }
```

says /rest as next url so its localhost:8080/test/test/rest

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` class.

```
@ApplicationPath("/") // the context root of you application
public class JaxRsConfig extends Application {

      private final Set<Class<?>> classes;

      public JaxRsConfig() {
        HashSet<Class<?>> c = new HashSet<>();
        c.add(Test.class); //repeat for all JAX-RS classes in your application

        classes = Collections.unmodifiableSet(c);
      }

      @Override
      public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return classes;
      }

}
```

With this you do not need a web.xml file.

Answer (score -1):

As there is a provider package specified so you can try with the following url-localhost:8080/com.latin.translator.app/test/rest